# How to efficiently find the index of value in a System.Numerics.Vector<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, vector, vectorization, system.numerics

I am exploring System.Numerics.Vector with .NET Framework 4.7.2 (the project I am working on cannot be migrated to .NET Core 3 and use the new Intrinsics namespace yet). The project is processing very large CSV/TSV files and we spend a lot of times looping through strings to find commas, quotes, etc. and I am trying to speed up the process.

So far, I have been able to use Vector to identify if a string contains a given character or not (using EqualsAny method). That’s great, but I want to go a little further. I want to efficiently find the index of that character using Vector. I do not know how. Below is he function I use to determine if a string contains a comma or not.

```
private static readonly char Comma = ',';
public static bool HasCommas(this string s)
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ReadOnlySpan<char> charSpan = s.AsSpan();
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector<ushort>> charAsVectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<char, Vector<ushort>>(charSpan);
    foreach (Vector<ushort> v in charAsVectors)
    {
        bool foundCommas = Vector.EqualsAny(v, StringExtensions.Commas);
        if (foundCommas)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    int numberOfCharactersProcessedSoFar = charAsVectors.Length * Vector<ushort>.Count;
    if (s.Length > numberOfCharactersProcessedSoFar)
    {
        for (int i = numberOfCharactersProcessedSoFar; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == ',')
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I understand that I could use the function above and scan the resulting Vector, but it would defeat the purpose of using a Vector. I heard about the new Intrinsics library that could help, but I cannot upgrade my project to .NET Core 3.

Given a Vector, how would you efficiently find the position of a character? Is there a clever trick that I am not aware of?

Comment: This is one of limitation of C# and CIL. It was complained very long time and there is no way to avoid `switch` like branches without `stackalloc` related new features. Because the standard of `struct` is different with C/C++. If you do not mark the field offset and packing, the runtime can realign your `struct` memory to optimize. Therefore, you cannot access the field by memory offset safely. So the C# does not support related syntax.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using vector to find the index of a char in string? There are easier ways.

Comment: I am using Vector in an attempt to speed up the string processing. Vector uses SIMD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) which allow to process multiple data points (in this case characters) in a single instruction.

Comment: Why you don't use SIMD in conjunction with parallelism? I think you can split string to (for example) 10 string and run your SIMD method on all of them in parallel tasks and use `Task.WhenAny`.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour, I understand what you are proposing, but i am focusing on a single row. How do I identify where the commas are given a single string? If I were able to implement this using SIMD this would be significantly faster than creating threads and managing them.

Comment: arent you trying to reinvent the wheel? Does string.IndexOf have some performance issues?

Comment: No, I am not trying to reinvent the wheel. I am processing hundreds of millions of CSV rows a week and saving just a couple milliseconds per row would result in reduce cost. Using string.IndexOf is just not an option when parsing CSV at scale.

Comment: Have you tried this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955433/use-c-sharp-vectort-simd-to-find-index-of-matching-element

Comment: Why don't you code everything you need in a .NET Core library and use that library from your existing .NET Framework project?